# psycopg2 connection with multihosts

Tags: postgresql, python, docker

I have 3 db servers on docker containers, and i used to connect like this from my python app:
`psycopg2.connect(host="db-0", user="user", password="password", database="data")` This works,but if i add more then 1 host it fails.

```
psycopg2.connect(host="db-0, db-1", user="user", password="password", database="data")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db-0, db-1" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

my package is:

psycopg2-2.8.4

python3.7

psql 11.5 on docker containers db-0 and db-1
I used pip install psycopg2 to install.

Comment: You can't connect to multiple servers like that. You need to do a `connect()` for each host

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ im not trying to connect to them all, i have psql HA and if psql master is changing i want my API to try the next server if one isnt working,

Comment: What happens when you use `psycopg2.connect("host=db-0,db-1 user=user password=password database=data")`? Passing as one string is what the documentation indicates is needed when using a libpq connection string. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ It should be possible -- at least I can't see in the documentation that it's not possible. I think it requires the connection string passed as a single argument, rather than using keywords.

Comment: Try removing the space between hostnames in `host="db-0, db-1"`

Comment: @mustaccio I did try and its the same

Comment: @Colin'tHart Can you write me an example of what that you mean  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by installing :

```
pip3 install postgres
```

and then command :

```
psycopg2.connect(host="db-0, db-1", user="user", password="password", database="data")
```

And now command works but it doesnt really route requests to the next db host list.
i already commanted it to psycopg2 git i hope someday they will fix it.
so here is my work around :

It query's all db containers in a loop, and if one of db returns in "SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();" query False, then it means it is the master.

so all my insert \ delete\ update query's goes to this in a function. (def db_master)
And all other "select" query's goes to the same loop in a different function that checks only the connection. (def db)

```
import psycopg2

hosts = ["db-0", "db-1"]

for i in hosts:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=data', user='user', host=i, password='password')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();")
    result = cur.fetchall()[0][0]
    if result is False:
        master = i
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname='data', user='user', host=master, password='password')
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a single libpq style connection string:

```
psycopg2.connect("host=db-0,db-1 user=user password=password dbname=data")
```

Comment: Doesnt work: psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db-0,db-1" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution